# Get the DDL for a function in a package

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there any way to get the DDL for a function in a package under a different user in Oracle?  I can see the package in SQL Developer under one of the users listed under 'Other users'.  I've tried using the `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` function:

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PACKAGE', 'MY_PACKAGE', 'OTHER_USER') FROM DUAL
```

But I get the following error:

> ORA-31603: object "MY_PACKAGE" of type PACKAGE not found in schema "OTHER_USER"

For the first parameter of the get_ddl function I tried PACKAGE_SPEC, and PACKAGE_BODY but this didn't seem to help.

Comment: Can you see the source code for the package in SQL Developer? And/or in all_source? And are you asking for code for the whole package or for a specific function?

Comment: Yep, I can see the source code by opening up the package and navigating via the connections/object explorer window in SQL Developer.  I'm really looking for the code for only one function if possible.

Comment: Do you have [the select_catalog role](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_metada.htm#ARPLS66868)? Sadly you'll only be able to get the package, not a specific function, though. You'd need to parse the function out somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this will help anyone, this is an old question, but I use this query (from Java) to rip all the procedures and functions off our server so we can put them in GIT. I'm using 12C.

```
with x as 
(
  SELECT owner, object_name, object_type
    FROM dba_objects
  WHERE owner LIKE 'OWNER_NAME_HERE'
    AND object_type IN ('PROCEDURE',  'FUNCTION')
)
SELECT  DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl (x.object_type, x.object_name, x.owner) as ddlcode FROM x;
```

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract code from package using get_dll, but you should instead provide the correct type of object (for example PACKAGE_BODY to get everything but the head/description)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're in SQL Developer, you can use the DDL command as well

[image]

```
clear screen
show user
ddl ords_demo.demo_pkg -- schema.package, gets the package and package body code
```

This is also available at the command line in SQLcl